# Alternative or better approach for *NgIf

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi I have several `*NgIf` conditions in my template. Based on the NgIf I display/render my components(different type of form) in the template. Example in one of my function (below)

```
private _onClick(cell:any){
        this._enableView = false;
        this._enableCreate = true;
        this._enableDelete = false;
        this._enableEdit = false;
    }
```

Which is to enable my create form in the template and hide other forms if its there. But doing so feel like bit wrong or redundant to me. Is there any better approach or suggestion instead of this approach?

Comment: What does you view (with `*ngIf`s look like)? Your isolated code snipped doesn't provide much information about its purpose.

Comment: Can you provide the template? From what I understand you have different forms which really make your code really long. Based from the code you provided, it seems that what you really want is toggling the buttons for this actions and not the whole form

Answer (score 4):

If it is possible to have a single state as suggested by Leguest I would recommend [`ngswitch`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html) used like this:

```
// Syntax for ngSwitch
<div [ngSwitch]="state">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'create'"> ... </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'view'">  ... </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'edit'"> ... </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'delete'"> ... </div>
    <div *ngSwitchDefault> ... </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise if you are using Angular 4.x you can take advantage of [`ngIf else`](https://medium.com/aviabird/ngif-else-lands-in-angular-2-0-a242940e54ff):

```
// Syntax for ngIf/Else
<div *ngIf=”condition; else elseBlock”>Truthy condition</div>
<template #elseBlock>Falsy condition</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure is it better or worse, but you can have one state property e.g. *this.state*, that contains string:

JS

```
 private _onClick(cell:any){
    this.state = 'create'
 }
```

HTML

```
<div *ngIf="state == 'create'">
    // create form 
</div>
<div *ngIf="state == 'view'">
   // view form
</div>
<div *ngIf="state == 'edit'">
  //  edit form
</div>
<div *ngIf="state == 'delete'">
 // delete form
</div>
```

So you replace part of your code into templates, I hope it reduce your js codebase

Comment: This sound like a sound approach although I would recommend using a more descriptive variable and an enum instead of plain string. Author may consider ngSwitch as well if their markup is similar to your example. It may even be worth breaking out the template into different sub components if this component is trying to do too much.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about enums too, but I don't remember does typescript support them. So you are right too

Comment: You just have to be careful with enums if you want to take advantage of AOT compilation- [dynamic component template => static template](https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/making-your-angular-2-library-statically-analyzable-for-aot-e1c6f3ebedd5#ca49)